# Restriction of $G$-equivariant sheaves to fixed locus

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, k-theory, algebraic-k-theory

Let $G$ be a group acting on a Noetherian scheme $X$ over $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathcal{E}$ be a $G$-equivariant coherent sheaf on $X$ where the support of $\mathcal{E}$ contains the fixed locus $X^G$. I have the following questions

1)Is the restriction of $\mathcal{E}$ to the fixed locus $X^G$ a locally free sheaf of constant rank?

2)If the first question is not true, what conditions should one add to get a locally free sheaf of constant rank on the restriction to $X^G$ out of a coherent $G$-equivariant sheaf?

I edited the question, original version did not have any restriction on the support and I wasn't asking the second question.

Comment: Did you leave out a condition? For a straightforward counterexample to the current statement, consider $Y$ is a proper closed $G$-equivariant subscheme of $X^G$: then $\mathcal{O}_Y$ is a $G$-equivariant coherent sheaf supported on a proper closed subscheme of $X^G$ and cannot be locally free.

Comment: Maybe I should add support of $\mathcal{E}$ must contain $X^G$.

Comment: That still doesn't fix it: take the direct sum of the previous example with the structure sheaf on $X^G$. (Or any other $\mathcal{E}$ satisfying your desired conclusion.)

Comment: I see, that's true. I don't know I kind of look for good conditions which can make the result true but still general enough.